# E: The package ros-indigo-librealsense needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: drivers, apt, synaptic

I am getting the following error.

```
E: The package ros-indigo-librealsense needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

It blocks every package installation with apt-get. What should I do?

EDIT: I can't really do anything with apt-get now. How to remove package by hand?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all ros-indigo-librealsense
```

Answer (score 0):

I would install YPPA - it helped me with missing dependancies when all else failed...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

`sudo apt-get update`

Good luck.